# See all dom events for an element

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, dom-events

I have a jQuery UI datepicker that, when you click on a date, clears my URL hash to `#`, and doesn't change the date in the textbox.

I assume there's some other JavaScript utility somewhere that has some sort of delegated event that's also being called, throwing an error, and killing the jquery handler.

How can I step through, and or see all delegated events match *this dom element*.

Comment: Dunno about that but you can open up Chrome's Dev Tools, go to the Scripts tab and put a breakpoint in the datepicker code and step through the JS code to see what gets executed.

Comment: Check this question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/446892/how-to-find-event-listeners-on-a-dom-node-in-javascript-or-in-debugging

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Chrome's dev tools can help with this:

1. Point Chrome at the page
2. Right-click the date in the jQuery UI datepicker and choose "inspect element".
3. On the far right-hand side, there's an accordian with various things. Near the bottom is "Event Listeners". (Current versions of Chrome's dev tools are very smart about this, including querying jQuery's handler chain.)
4. Expand the "Event Listeners" tree item and you'll see a list of hooked events related to that element, even if the handler isn't set specifically on *that* element. (For instance, if you did this with the upvote button on the question, you'd see that `click` is hooked both for `a.vote-up-off` and `document`.) So you can kick around those to see what direct and delegated handlers relate to that event for that element.

Other than that, you could use the un-minified version of jQuery and walk through the event dispatch when you click the date in the datepicker.

And of course, [Gabe's shown](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11087155/157247) how you can get the jQuery-specific handlers via the undocumented jQuery `events` data. (That won't show you delegated handlers (unless you walk the ancestor tree), and won't show you non-jQuery handlers that might be attached, but it's still pretty useful stuff.)

Comment: You're a god among men, TJ. Thank you as always.

Comment: @AdamRackis: LOL No worries, hope that helps.

Answer (score 4):

With jQuery you can see all the elements events by accessing the `events` key of the data.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/N4Y4R/)

Example:

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" id="myelement" />​
```

**JS**

```
$(function() {


    var myelement = $('#myelement');
    myelement.click(function() {

        console.log('anonymous event');

    });

    myelement.click(anotherEvent);
    myelement.change(anotherEvent);

    var events = myelement.data('events');

    console.log('Number of click events:' + events.click.length);
    console.log('Number of change events:' + events.change.length);

});

function anotherEvent(){
    console.log('another event');   
}
```

Comment: Will that also pick up delegated events?  ie  `$(document).on("click", "a", function() { ... });`  if `#myelement` is an anchor, will it show this handler?

Comment: @AdamRackis: No, it won't. It will only show you directly-hooked handlers, not handlers further up the tree that may also get called: http://jsbin.com/ujipuz Of course, that doesn't mean you can't walk the element's ancestors and repeat the process for each of them, which would give you the full picture. +1 to Gabe

Comment: I misunderstood, thought you were looking for a programatic solution rather than a debugging tool :)

Comment: @Gabe - no worried - your answer is actually pretty useful to know, even if it doesn't apply to my particular case here.  Thanks.